# if i carry enough money/ have carried enough money

Tags: conditional-constructions

If I carry enough money, I will definitely go and watch a movie on weekend.

vs

If I have carried enough money, I will definitely go and watch a movie on weekend.

Which one is correct? situation: today is tuesday and I am talking about things I would do on weekend.

Comment: We don't use ***carry*** like this (where I assume you mean ***have, possess***, in the sense of "owning"). If you mean ***actually have the money in your pocket*** (as opposed to having enough in the bank so you can pay using a card without being overdrawn) that would be expressed as *If I **have** enough money **on me**, I'll go to the cinema*.

Comment: How much money was the suspect carrying? How much money do you have?

Answer (score 1):

"carry" is the present tense.

"have carried" is the present perfect (a type of past tense)

Something important to note about the English present tense, I quote Wikipedia:

> Use of the present tense does not always imply present time. In
>   particular, the present tense is often used to refer to future
>   events... (My train leaves at 3 o'clock this afternoon). This is
>   particularly the case in condition clauses... 
> [Present tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_tense)

So you are the using present tense correctly in the first sentence. The second sentence uses a past tense which is not right at all, because you're not talking about how much money you had in the past.

Also, we don't use "carry" to refer to how much money we possess. Generally we use "to have".

One final point, "weekend" needs to have an article/adjective/determiner before it. Most commonly you'll use the definite article (the), or the indefinite article (a).

You should say "the weekend". The definite article "the", as opposed to the indefinite article "a", identifies a particular weekend, and this particular weekend means the next one. You can also say "a weekend", which doesn't specify which weekend, it means one weekend in the future you will go to watch a movie.

So a right way to say what you want to say is:

> If I ***have*** enough money, I will definitely go and watch a movie
>   on ***the*** weekend.

I know all these rules are confusing. Your first sentence in the question is understandable, it just doesn't sound like native speech. So you would be understood, it would just sound a little strange.

Comment: You covered pretty much everything here, very clearly. The only minor point I'd make is that ***on** the weekend* is very much a US usage. In the UK it would almost always be ***at** the weekend* (or feasibly ***over*** if you wanted to specifically imply *sometime **during** the weekend*, as opposed to the weekend being "a point in time" that comes between each Mon-Fri working week).

Answer (score 1):

As several people have pointed out, it is not idiomatic to use *carry* in this way; but *bring* is idiomatic, so we can avoid that difficulty by using "bring" instead of "carry".

*If I bring enough money* and *if I have brought enough money* are both perfectly natural and idiomatic; and (as is often the case with questions about whether or not to use perfect, continuous, past perfect constructions) the difference is *not at all* about the objective situation being described, but *entirely* about how the speaker is choosing to describe the events.

If you say "If I have brought enough money" you are looking backwards from the (future) time at which you consider whether you will go to the cinema. This suggests that it will not be until that time that you will know whether you have brought enough money (which is a little unlikely; but not impossible)

If you say "If I bring enough money", you are looking forwards to that time, and presumably making the decision in advance.

But here is another example where the two possibilities both make sense. Suppose you're having a garage sale, so you don't know how much money you will make (earn). Then

> If I make enough money, I'll go and watch a movie.
>
> If I have made enough money, I'll go and watch a movie.

both make sense, and have no objective difference in their meaning (in either case you won't know until after the sale whether you have enough money). But in the second case you are implicitly imagining yourself after the sale and looking backwards.